# Is there a working RDP solution for Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)?

Tags: virtualbox, remote-desktop, vnc

I've spent about 10+ hours working on this. I may be having issues because of my particular problem scenario. I'm trying to RDP using Windows Remote Desktop to connect to a Virtual Machine running on my network.

I have no problem connecting to the Remote PC with Windows Remote Desktop, in a Windows10 > Windows10 scenario.

I have OracleVirtualBox installed on the Remote Windows10 PC, the VM is running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver).

When I try to use the same computer and Windows Remote Desktop to connect to the VM running on the remote PC nothing works.

I've tried the XRDP, XFCE4 solutions.

I've enabled bridged netowrking in the VM, I also have remote server enabled under display in virtual box.

Firewall exceptions were added to the VM (I literally allow access through port 3389, I also attempted a schema using port 3388, with no success).

I've pretty much put my "RDP to a VM on the local network" project on hold for now.

I really doubt this is some problem that I specifically am having.

note: I'm also having issues with VNC, and TightVNCServer. I plan on taking my time with that today, as an alternative to RDP.

THANKS!